# Child can't write into shared memory ( fifo - linked list in c)

Tags: c, linked-list, shared-memory, fifo

I have to resolve problem of producer and cunsumers. I can use only POSIX (without System V). I make small steps and try to implement simple sharing with child procces now. Unfortunately, child can't add anything to fifo.

```
        typedef struct elem{
        int val;
        bool a;
        bool b;
        bool c;
        struct elem * next;
    } elem_t;
    typedef struct fifo
    {
        elem_t * head;
        elem_t * tail;
        int size;
    }fifo_t;

fifo_t* add_elem( fifo_t*, const int);
fifo_t* remove_elem( fifo_t*);
fifo_t* init(void);

void list_print( const fifo_t* );
void list_print_elem(const elem_t* );


int main()
{

    int fd;
    void *addr;
    fifo_t * queue = NULL;
    queue = init();
    add_elem(queue,5);
    add_elem(queue,8);
    list_print(queue);
    remove_elem(queue);
    list_print(queue);

    fd = shm_open("/test",  O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0666);
    size_t size_fifo = sizeof queue;
    ftruncate(fd,size_fifo);
    addr = mmap(NULL, size_fifo, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED ,fd, 0);
    pid_t pidA = fork();
    if(pidA==0){
        fifo_t * q = (fifo_t*) addr;
        add_elem(q,5);
        exit(0);
    }
    else{
        int status;
        waitpid(pidA, &status, 0);
        list_print(queue);

    }   
    munmap(addr,size_fifo);
    shm_unlink("/test");
    return 0;
}
```

and method add:

```
    fifo_t * add_elem(fifo_t* s, int i)
{
  elem_t* p = malloc( 1 * sizeof(*p) );

  if( NULL == p )
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "IN %s, %s: malloc() failed\n", __FILE__, "list_add");
      return s; 
    }

  p->val = i;
  p->next = NULL;



  if( NULL == s )
    {
      printf("Queue not initialized\n");
      free(p);
      return s;
    }
  else if( NULL == s->head && NULL == s->tail )
    {
      /* printf("Empty list, adding p->num: %d\n\n", p->num);  */
      s->head = s->tail = p;
      s->size +=1;
      return s;
    }

  else
    {
      /* printf("List not empty, adding element to tail\n"); */
      s->tail->next = p;
      s->tail = p;
      s->size +=1;
    }

  return s;
}
```

my output like that:

[image]

Main procces can add and remove elements.
Child should add val =5 and increase size but it didnt make it.
Can someone explain my mistakes?

Comment: You can't share memory allocated via `malloc()` across processes.

Comment: @EOF so only way is change list on table?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.   Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

Comment: function `fork()` has three possible return values: 1) <0, 2) =0, 3) >0.  The posted code fails to handle the <0 condition

Comment: @user3629249 there is no problem with fork... And it is not final version of code. Child is created and execute lines but didnt have impact on shared fifo.

Comment: @Xalion, not checking for errors is a MAJOR problem. Suggest you learn to always check for errors.   My answer says why the code is not working as you seem to expect.

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem.  Otherwise, the question is off-topic and will soon be closed.

Answer (score 0):

the first few lines of the posted code work with a queue on the stack, that was initialized via a call to `init()`.

After the call to `mmap()` a new queue is defined as being located in the memory allocated via the call to `mmap()`.

The posted code fails to initialize that new queue.

Then after the call to `fork()`, the child tries to add a entry to the queue on the (uninitialized) queue in the memory allocated by `mmap()`  so, naturally, that entry is NOT on the queue that is on the stack

The call to `list_print()` is passed a parameter that points to the queue on the stack.  so will never see the entry in the memory allocated by `mmap()`